# How to create new line for multiple variables values JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I want to put a `\n` (Line Separator) between the variable string values. So the data shows like:

```
test
test1
test2
test3
```

How do I accomplish this following JSON practices?

My example:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
      "sessionID":xxxxx,
      "synchronize":false,
      "sourceRequest":{
        "numberOrigin":xxxxxx,
        "type":"x",
        "description":test + "\\n" + test2 "\\n" +  test3  "\\n" + test4,
        "userID":xxxxxxxx,
        "contact":{
          "name":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "phoneNumber":"xxxxxxxxxx",
          "email":xxxx,
          "department":"xxxxx"
        },
```

Comment: Some plus signs seem missing. Did you mean `test + "\\n" + test2 + "\\n" +  test3 + "\\n" + test4`?

Comment: What is the issue now ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `"\\n"` says to put a literal `\n` in the string - 2 chars. You should just use `"\n"` to say that its a new line - 1 char.

Note if viewing in Windows Notepad, `\n` is not enough for a new line.

Comment: correct! also, for source and documentation on escaping in JSON, it's directly available on http://json.org/

Answer (score 3):

A simple ' ' (space character) is enough to do what is needed, the json key does hold a string after all, if you need something more prominent you can use '\t', refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp) for more.